# InnerHtml won't update src of my image

Tags: php, javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to update the src of an image, but on site it show only
 `<img class="imagedisplayor" style="float: none;" alt="" width="200" height="200" src=""/>`

Here's the code:

```
function ajaxFigure(){
var url = 'index.php?option=com_fabrik&format=raw&view=plugin&task=userAjax&method=imgclasse';
var product = Fabrik.blocks.form_8.formElements.orders___product.getValue();
var update = $('orders___image').firstChild;
new Request({
    url: url,
    data: {
        method: 'imgclasse',
        'product': product
    },
    onComplete: function (r) {
        update.src = 'http://www.youtraining.eu/preview' + r.replace('images/', 'images/');
        document.getElementById('orders___image').innerHTML = '<img class=\'imagedisplayor\' style=\'float:none;\' alt=

\'\'  width=\'200\' height=\'200\'  src="' + r + '">'
    }
}).send();


}
```

and here my imgClasse()

```
function imgclasse() {
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$IdClasse = JRequest::getVar("product", "");  

$query = "SELECT product_image from products WHERE id=$IdClasse LIMIT 1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
echo $result; 


}
```

Updated with everything..
What I'm trying to do is to get shown an image for every element of a dropdown list that's an entry on a database. Js and PHP are the only method I can use, cause i'm inside a CMS.

Changed var product=  Fabrik.blocks.form_8.formElements.orders___product.getValue();
and now it returns the right value.. but problem still remain

Comment: Can you show more CODES?

Comment: `getElementByID("....").....` I don't see that ID, Try using Jquery it will be a lot easier.

Comment: God!, I thought I had weak eyes. Thanks @jcho360.

Comment: What is: `r.replace("images/","images/")`  suppose to do?

Comment: Guys please, to help @Gabriele Prestifilippo  benefit from the reasons why his post is being down-voted, please state those reasons as to why you are down-voting his post, at least in a comment. so that future viewers of this post will also benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your codes:

```
onComplete: function (r) {
        update.src = 'http://www.mysite.com/preview' + r.replace('images/', 'images/');
        document.getElementById('orders___image').innerHTML = '<img class=\'imagedisplayor\' style=\'float:none;\' alt=\'\'  width=\'200\' height=\'200\'  src=' + r + '>'
    }
```

I assume `update.src` is an object defined as:

```
var update= {src:"..."};
```

So, when you pass the value to the `.src` key of this object as:

`update.src = 'http://www.mysite.com/preview' + r.replace('images/', 'images/');`,

then the:

`document.getElementById('orders___image').innerHTML = '<img class=\'imagedisplayor\' style=\'float:none;\' alt=\'\'  width=\'200\' height=\'200\'  src=' + r + '>'`,

> Exchange `r` with `update.src` because the value of `r` is what you want `update.src` to contain including the replacement made by the `.replace('images/', 'images/')`

So it should be :

`document.getElementById('orders___image').innerHTML = '<img class=\'imagedisplayor\' style=\'float:none;\' alt=\'\'  width=\'200\' height=\'200\'  src=' + update.src + '>`'

You can confirm to see if your r variable really has something in it or if at all it's recognized by doing something like:

```
onComplete: function (r) {

  console.log(r)
//Before running any other code
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: And if you could tell... What is: `r.replace("images/","images/")` suppose to do?

Comment: That's would be the path for my images, check now the code. I'm very glad for your help.

Comment: Noticed that value of (r) is empty.. it should be /images/nameofproduct.jpg

Comment: in your PHP, can you try to `var_dump($result)`..? Please tell what you see

Comment: Before you start dealing with the client side scripts i.e. Javascript/jQuery, you have to make sure that, Your Server Side Script(PHP) and your database Queries are communicating as expected... Test to see that you are getting the expected results from that end. After that, you can now come to jQuery for your front end results.

Comment: should I var_dump($result) after $result = $db->loadResult(); ?
where i can see the output?

Comment: Yes, after you have assigned values to the variable $result, I think that should be after the echo or before it..

Answer (score 0):

The Short Answer:

You aren't updating the image source with the new value. You're updating it with the value provided to the function. You also need to provide double quotes to the src attribute when you concatenate it in.

```
document.getElementById('orders___image').innerHTML = '<img class=\'imagedisplayor\' style=\'float:none;\' alt=\'\'  width=\'200\' height=\'200\'  src="' + r + '">'
```

Suggestions:

If I were you and running into this issue, I'd do a console.log of your new image path to verify the generated path against your actual image path. It's hard to tell without knowing the value of `r` being supplied to your function.

The other main thing that jumps out at me is that you don't need to completely replace the image element. It would be cleaner if you got a reference to the image element directly and then updated its `src` attribute to be the new location. Again, it's difficult to give you anything more specific without more information.